# create four filter in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I create this search sql. But i want only searching those peaple whose are in blood group a+ , thana khilgoan division dhaka and district dhaka. But my search result show nothing

```
Select          d.user_id,
                d.firstname,
                d.`blood_group`,
                a.`city_thana`,
                a.`division`,
                a.`district` 
From            donar d 
natural join    addrsess a
where           `blood_group` = 'A+' 
and             a.`city_thana` = 'Khilgoan' 
and             a.`division` = 'Dhaka' 
and             a.`district` = 'Dhaka'
```

Comment: Do you have any people that meet those conditions?

Comment: We would need to see the table definitions for donar and address to ensure a natural join exists along with some same data in A to ensure matching criteria exists.

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to see the table devotions, the `natural join` may be messing up the query  since all columns with the same name will be joined against

Comment: And this should be a comment rather an answer since it doesn't help to solve the issue at hand.

Comment: how i add filter in sql. and operator mess up all. when i use or operator then it show me extra result and my filter not work ...

Comment: when i select coutry name 'X' it filter my selection when i select city name 'Y' it then it show the result where country x and city y found....

Answer (score 0):

You can or should perform `Natural Join` only when you sure that both table has a common field with same name else perform a `INNER JOIN` explicitly. Try modifying your query with an explicit join like

```
Select          d.user_id,
                d.firstname,
                d.`blood_group`,
                a.`city_thana`,
                a.`division`,
                a.`district` 
From            donar d 
INNER JOIN      addrsess a ON d.user_id = a.user_id  (may be other column)
where           d.`blood_group` = 'A+' 
and             a.`city_thana` = 'Khilgoan' 
and           'Dhaka' IN (a.`division`,a.`district`)
```

Comment: when i select coutry name 'X' it filter my selection when i select city name 'Y' it then it show the result where country x and city y found....

Comment: Then you should add a filter with Country name as well. try the query in answer and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This code solve the problem...

```
  select d.user_id,d.firstname,d.`blood_group`,a.`city_thana`,a.`division`,a.`district` from donar d natural join address a
where `blood_group` like 'Bo' and `city_thana`='Bangsal'  like `division`='DHAKA' and `district`='DHAKA'
```